# My WebMatrix site has span elements not rendering hidden in Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, jquery, html, hidden, webmatrix

I have the following block of html (w/razor) in my page:

```
<td class="upperTable">
                            <div id="picLeftButton" class="pictureButton" unselectable="on" style="margin-right: 5px;">&lArr;</div><div id="picRightButton" unselectable="on" class="pictureButton" style="margin-left: 5px;">&rArr;</div>
                            <span id="picm" class="mugshot"><span class="fileNameDisplay"><span style="color: #808080; font-size: 1.1em;">Pic Currently Stored:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>@if((string)Session["gMugshotFileName"]==null || (string)Session["gMugshotFileName"]==""){<span class="noFile">[NONE]</span>}else{@Session["gMugshotFileName"]}</span>Mugshot:
                                <input id="mugUp" name="mugUp" type="file" maxlength="50" /><button onclick="mugshotClearPicVE()" id="MugshotClearPic" type="button">Clear Pic</button><input id="mugIsPicClear" name="mugIsPicClear" type="hidden" value="" />
                                @if(Session["gMugshot"]!=null)
                                {
                                    <img id="Mugshot" class="picDisplay" style="width: 400px; height: 350px;" alt="Mugshot" src="/ShowImage.cshtml?Id=@Session["gEntryID"]" />
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <img id="MugshotNoPic" class="picDisplay" style="width: 400px; height: 350px;" alt="No Picture Loaded" src="/Images/noPicture.png" />
                                }
                                </span>
                            <span id="pic1" class="mugshot" hidden="hidden"><span class="fileNameDisplay"><span style="color: #808080; font-size: 1.1em;">Pic Currently Stored:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>@if((string)Session["gPOIPic1FileName"]==null || (string)Session["gPOIPic1FileName"]==""){<span class="noFile">[NONE]</span>}else{@Session["gPOIPic1FileName"]}</span>Picture 1:
                                <input id="picUp1" name="picUp1" type="file" maxlength="50" accept="image/*" /><button onclick="POIPic1ClearPicVE()" id="POIPic1ClearPic" type="button">Clear Pic</button><input id="POIPic1IsPicClear" name="POIPic1IsPicClear" type="hidden" value="" />
                                @if(Session["gPOIPic1"]!=null)
                                {
                                    <img id="POIPic1" class="picDisplay" style="width: 400px; height: 350px;" alt="POIPic1" src="/ShowImage2.cshtml?Id=@Session["gEntryID"]" />
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <img id="POIPic1NoPic" class="picDisplay" style="width: 400px; height: 350px;" alt="No Picture Loaded" src="/Images/noPicture.png" />
                                }
                                </span>
                            <span id="pic2" class="mugshot" hidden="hidden"><span class="fileNameDisplay"><span style="color: #808080; font-size: 1.1em;">Pic Currently Stored:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>@if((string)Session["gPOIPic2FileName"]==null || (string)Session["gPOIPic2FileName"]==""){<span class="noFile">[NONE]</span>}else{@Session["gPOIPic2FileName"]}</span>Picture 2:
                                <input id="picUp2" name="picUp2" type="file" maxlength="50" accept="image/*" /><button onclick="POIPic2ClearPicVE()" id="POIPic2ClearPic" type="button">Clear Pic</button><input id="POIPic2IsPicClear" name="POIPic2IsPicClear" type="hidden" value="" />
                                @if(Session["gPOIPic2"]!=null)
                                {
                                    <img id="POIPic2" class="picDisplay" style="width: 400px; height: 350px;" alt="POIPic2" src="/ShowImage3.cshtml?Id=@Session["gEntryID"]" />
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <img id="POIPic2NoPic" class="picDisplay" style="width: 400px; height: 350px;" alt="No Picture Loaded" src="/Images/noPicture.png" />
                                }
                                </span>
                            <span id="pic3" class="mugshot" hidden="hidden"><span class="fileNameDisplay"><span style="color: #808080; font-size: 1.1em;">Pic Currently Stored:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>@if((string)Session["gPOIPic3FileName"]==null || (string)Session["gPOIPic3FileName"]==""){<span class="noFile">[NONE]</span>}else{@Session["gPOIPic3FileName"]}</span>Picture 3:
                                <input id="picUp3" name="picUp3" type="file" maxlength="50" accept="image/*" /><button onclick="POIPic3ClearPicVE()" id="POIPic3ClearPic" type="button">Clear Pic</button><input id="POIPic3IsPicClear" name="POIPic3IsPicClear" type="hidden" value="" />
                                @if(Session["gPOIPic3"]!=null)
                                {
                                    <img id="POIPic3" class="picDisplay" style="width: 400px; height: 350px;" alt="POIPic3" src="/ShowImage4.cshtml?Id=@Session["gEntryID"]" />
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <img id="POIPic3NoPic" class="picDisplay" style="width: 400px; height: 350px;" alt="No Picture Loaded" src="/Images/noPicture.png" />
                                }
                            </span></br>
```

You'll notice that there are four spans, and the idea here is to "page" through them using the manually (from divs) created buttons, which actually hides/unhides them using jQuery (don't ask why I didn't just use the "button" element, but that's irrelevant).  The problem I am having here is that the worst browser in the world (always unanimously IE) won't hide the last three spans, in fact, it won't even start hidden, that is, all four "pages" are haphazardly displayed on the page, where I have allocated space for only one at a time. (The idea is that there are four "pages", the first does not start hidden, and the other three do).  In any case, whether I use hidden="hidden", try to render the span attribute as hidden ($(".mugshot").attr('hidden' true)) in jQuery on page load, or whether I use "display: none"  IE fails to interpret any of these solutions, like always, causing me quite a headache.

Is this because it is in a table?  If so, what other way can I select these elements for use with all browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, in order to solve this, I had to add a couple of things.  First off, I had to add style="display: none" to the three elements I wanted to begin the page hidden, on the html level.  Then I had to add some lines to jQuery.

Before modifications:

```
                $("#picm").prop("hidden", true);
                $("#pic1").prop("hidden", false);
                $("#pic2").prop("hidden", true);
                $("#pic3").prop("hidden", true);
```

After modifications:

```
                $("#picm").prop("hidden", true);
                $("#pic1").prop("hidden", false);
                $("#pic2").prop("hidden", true);
                $("#pic3").prop("hidden", true);
                $("#picm").css("display", "none");
                $("#pic1").css("display", "inline");
                $("#pic1").css("display", "normal");
                $("#pic2").css("display", "none");
                $("#pic3").css("display", "none");
```

Notice that I had to not only had to repeat the three lines to hide in IE using css display, but also had to add a fourth (.css('display', 'inline')) for IE and a fifth (.css('display', 'normal')) for FireFox.

If only all browsers could be as smart as Chrome... But I would settle for no browsers being a stupid as IE, though...